# if $X \subseteq Y $ are flats s.t. $r(Y) = r(X)-1$ then $\exists$ hyperplane $H$ s.t. $Y = H \cap X$.

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, probability-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, matroids

Let $X$ and $Y$ be flats of a matroid $M$ such that $Y \subseteq X$ and $r(Y) = r(X)-1$. How can i prove that $M$ has a hyperplane $H$ such that $Y = H \cap X$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $r$ denotes the rank. We shall use the following

**Lemma.** Let $A\subset B$ be any flats of a matroid $M$ such that $r(A)=r(B)<\infty$. Then $A = B$. $\square$

Now pick any element $x\in X\setminus Y$. Let $\mathcal F$ be the family of flats $Z$ in $M$ such that $Y\subset Z\subset M\setminus\{x\}$. Since $Y\in\mathcal F$, $\mathcal F$ is nonempty. It is easy to show that the family $\mathcal F$ is inductive. So $\mathcal F$ contains a maximal element, say, $H$. Suppose for a contradiction that $\overline{H\cup\{x\}}\ne M$. Pick any element $y\in M\setminus \overline{H\cup\{x\}}$. By the maximality of $H$, $a\in\overline{H\cup\{y\}}$. By the Exchange Property, $y\in\overline{H\cup\{x\}}$, a contradiction. Since $H\in\mathcal F$, $Y\subset H\cap X$.

Now we assume that $r(Y)$ is finite, otherwise it can happen that $Y=X=M$ and there are no proper subset $H$ of $M$ such that $Y=H\cap X$. Suppose for a contradiction that there is an element $z\in (H\cap X)\setminus Y$. Let $Z=\overline{Y\cup\{z\}}$. Then $Y\subset Z\subset X$. Thus $r(Y)\le r(Z)\le r(X)$.
Since $Y\ne Z$, by Lemma $r(Y)<r(Z)$. So $r(Z)=r(X)$ and again by Lemma we have $Z=X$. But $Z\subset H$
and $x\in X\setminus H$, a contradiction.

Comment: do you have a proof for this lemma or is it proved in James Oxley, " matroid theory", second edition?

Comment: what do you mean by the family is inductive?

Comment: I will repeat the question "what do you mean by the family is inductive?" And why you are sure from this?do you mean that it is a chain?

Comment: what is a in the second to last line from below in the first paragraph?

Comment: is $\mathcal{F} = Z$?

Comment: why this should happen in the last paragraph $r(Z) = r(X)$?

Comment: Why $Z \subset H$?

Comment: What is the contradiction at the end of the second paragraph? It is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just as you would for a representable matroid. Take a basis for $Y$, then add an element from $X$ to get a basis for $X$. Extend this to a basis for the entire ground set, then delete the single element of $X$ to get a basis for your hyperplane.

Comment: the answer does not make sense. please clarify or add more details. please consider $Y \subseteq X$ not the other way. and also what you are saying is not quite a proof.

Comment: what part of the answer does not make sense to you? There are a few things you could prove just following the definitions of a matroid: every set has a basis, every independent set can be extended to a basis, and that the closure of the basis you obtain in the end is indeed a hyperplane.

Comment: thanks for edit and thanks for answer. it would be great to write the answer as complete as possible.anyway i could accept your answer without editing but it could be confusing for someone who may see the answer in future.